# How to make chrome browser display a csv file instead of downloading it?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to set Chrome so that instead of always downloading a csv file (with response header 'Content-Type: text/csv'), I can have the file displayed directly in the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest [CSV Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/csv-reader/dnioinfbhmclclfdbcnlfgbojdpdicde?hl=en), a Chrome extension that stops CSV files from downloading and transforms them to a simple HTML table. It also remembers your settings for each url.

> Transforms raw csv data into a simple html table, easily readable on the browser.

> This extension transforms raw csv to a simple html table in seconds, and shows it online in the same tab.

Comment: I tried that extension already, but it does not prevent Chrome downloading a CSV file if it has 'Content-type: text/csv' :(

Comment: What if you used yet another extension ;) to modify the Content-type first?
[Modify Content-Type](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka?hl=en-US)
`Change the response content type to force documents to open in or outside the browser window or in a special view mode.` Still in beta however.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well with modheader.com extension. Unfortunately, this does not give you fine control over what values of headers get modified -- it just crudely overwrites every request with the single type you speficy. This does allow the browser to not download the CSV file, but is far too crude to rely on regularly. I tried the extension you suggested, but seems outdated and did not seem to work. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it `Content-Type` to `text/csv` use `text/plain`. CSV files are practically plain text files so by defining `text/plain` you allow browser to display it inline as a plain text.

If you need to view contents of a CSV file as a table I think you need to download it and open in some spreadsheet viewer.