# how to display uploaded file from writable/uploads in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

**In Codeigniter4 how to show the path of uploaded file from the writable/uploads folder?**

The file may be an image, doc, pdf or CSV.
I upload the file using the below code and store it in DB.

`$file->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads', $fileName);`

all uploaded records are listed on a page and have to open the uploaded CSV/excel in a new tab from the listing page.

but I did not get the path from the writable/uploads folder to open in a new tab.

`<?=WRITEPATH.'uploads/'.$allList->documentCsv?>`

when I copy the link and open it on a tab it downloaded.

Please explain how to show the path.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367690/how-to-make-chrome-browser-display-a-csv-file-instead-of-downloading-it

Comment: can you make more clear to this? you only want out with path like `/var/www/html/ci4/writable/uploads/file.csv` or the page in browser instead of showing the value of csv, it is downloaded? which one?

Comment: @Doelmi I want to show the file on a new tab from ```WRITEPATH.'uploads/```. The file may be an image, doc, pdf or CSV ( for CSV or excel there may be different ways).

Comment: @user19204293 do you have filename in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarification.
I get this summary.

You want to show file binary value but instead of download you wanna show it in browser.

I have this code for you

```php
public function showFile()
{
    helper("filesystem");
    $path = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/';
    $filename = 'logo-at.png';

    $fullpath = $path . $filename;
    $file = new \CodeIgniter\Files\File($fullpath, true);
    $binary = readfile($fullpath);
    return $this->response
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', $file->getMimeType())
            ->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="' . $file->getBasename() . '"')
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setBody($binary);
}
```

The supported extension will show the file value in browser. If not, it will downloaded.

Reference in documentation:

1. https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/files.html#getting-a-file-instance
2. https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/outgoing/response.html#http-responses

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful to me, my problem is resolved now.